# Nodemcu sleep mode works but still consumes too much power

Tags: sleep

I would like to reduce the power consumption on my ESP8266 devices with a built in USB to UART.

I used this function :
  system_deep_sleep_set_option(0);
  system_deep_sleep(5 * 1000000);

This function works ok and reduces consumption to 0.1mA if I use Nodemcu with the serial connector.

However, it only reduces consumption from 90mA to 20mA when I use the Nodemcu which has USB connector (Lua Nodemcu WIFI Network Development Board Based ESP8266).

The difference between the two is that the second Nodemcu has a UARTtoUSB module. So I suppose that this is what causes the power consumption during the sleep mode.

Is it possible to make the second one only consume 0.1mA as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage regulators on the NodeMCU board consume about 10ma.
Please see this post for a detailed explanation:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/719